# Cant install gnome control center

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ppa

[image]

Had installed Pop!OS PPA and everything went to hell, settings were altered and it asked me to upgrade to POP OS in the about section of the settings app. I run ubuntu with gnome. I removed the Pop Os ppa after doing a bit of search. Now my settings app is gone keyboard shortcuts that I had set up dont work plus many other things.

Comment: helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245159/system-settings-wont-open-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-adding-system76-pop-ppa/1266235#1266235

Comment: No dice. Tried all the solutions

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. I removed the POP OS varient of the dependencies manually using the sudo apt remove command then went back to install each of them.
Settings app is back (gnome control center). A lot of things are still off such as fonts. I assume I'll slowly fix those.